# Basic Theme Editing in VirtoCommerce

Tags: virtocommerce

I am running VirtoCommerce 2.4.644.  I have a small collection of products and they are not placed in category folders in my catalog.  How do I edit the default theme to just show all the most recent items on the home page in one big grid view?

Following the [documentation for theme development](http://docs.virtocommerce.com/display/vc2devguide/Theme+Development), I tried to edit css/html, but I can't tell which templates control what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current release there is no out of the box support for themes retriving and showing products that don't belong to any category. In the latest dev, there is "collections.all.products" property that can be used in liquid to get all the products and it should include the ones in the root.

Comment: Okay, so it sounds like I just need to assign a category to my products then.  I don't see a way of moving an existing product into a new category though.  Looks like I'm going to need to start with a fresh catalog and make sure to place the products into categories.